# Vaadin - Refresh grid after row modification

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I create simple grid with data from database:

```
BeanItemContainer<Customer> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(Customer.class, customerRepository.findAll());
Grid grid = new Grid(container);
```

To edit each row the button was created:

```
Button edit = new Button("Edit", clickEvent -> openWindow((Customer) grid.getSelectedRows().iterator().next()));
```

This open new window with edit form. After all changes accepted, I must manually refresh whole page to see modification on Grid. My question is:

How refresh only Grid after modification of any row entry?
And how save those modifications to database (maybe beanItemContainer could do it)?

Comment: See [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51871370/642706) but for Vaadin 8 instead of 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bug. Grid doesn't update itself after changes were done in underlying container nor has any reasonable method to refresh. There are several hacks around this issue i.e.

```
grid.clearSortOrder();
```

or

```
grid.setEditorEnabled(true);
grid.setEditorEnabled(false);
```

SSCCE:

```
TextField text =  new TextField("Edit");
Grid grid;
BeanItemContainer<Customer> container;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    container = new BeanItemContainer<>(Customer.class, Arrays.asList(new Customer("1"), new Customer("2")));
    grid = new Grid(container);
    Button open = new Button("open");
    open.addClickListener(this :: openListener);
    Button save = new Button("save");
    save.addClickListener(this :: saveListener);
    layout.addComponents(grid, open, save, text);
    setContent(layout);
}

private void openListener(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent){
    text.setValue(((Customer) (grid.getSelectedRow())).getName());
}
private void saveListener(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent){
    Customer c = (Customer) grid.getSelectedRow();
    c.setName(text.getValue());
    grid.clearSortOrder();
}
```

Possible duplicate [Update Grid with a fresh set of data, in Vaadin 7.4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204674/update-grid-with-a-fresh-set-of-data-in-vaadin-7-4-app)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion with `clearSortOrder()` works perfectly. 
Moreover for anybody who wants refresh only one row, there are some hints:
[Vaadin Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/9319379/9334479)

Comment: If this is a bug, do you have the related Vaadin bug tracker number/link?

Answer (score 12):

With Vaadin 8, the following works to refresh the grid after rows have been added or removed or the underlying data has been changed:

```
grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in Vaadin 8. I need to setItems explicitly each time.

Comment: @Aubergine if you set the data with setItems() to begin with, then yes since that's creates a DataProvider that wraps the list of items and so you need to update the items expliitly.

Comment: @Aubergine but if you use a DataProvider that dynamically fetches data from a data store (e.g., a RDBMS) then the refreshAll() method works as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

Since Vaadin 7.7.4 there is a `refreshRows(Object ... itemIds)` and a `refreshAllRows()` method in the grid: https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/16765

Comment: it is this method, but does nothing (Vaadin 7.7.9)

Comment: It used to work when I posted this answer (almost a year ago). If I were you I would check if the data is up to date in the container.

Comment: When the Grid is **disabled**, and rows are added or modified  **refreshAllRows()** doesn't work, but **clearSortOrder()** does

Comment: Do these guys even have control over their api. Wtf for refreshing a table. You should just give it a list of items and it should render it, how hard can it be. Forcably working with Vaadin for work and I hate it. Have been doing web dev for 15 years and never had to deal with this crap.

Answer (score 0):

I had to **explicitly call** `grid.setItems()` after each call to `saveListener` event to make my Vaadin 8.3 Grid refresh data inside the grid. It's strange that the visual grid state does **not** reflect edited values.

Scala implementation:

```
var advicesList : mutable.MutableList[Advice] = null

private def initGrid() = {
  advicesList = mutable.MutableList(itmemsFromDB: _*)
  setItems(advicesList.asJava)

  getEditor.addSaveListener((event) => {
      val bean = event.getBean
      Notification.show("Saved value: " + bean)

      // ==== RELOAD GRID ITEMS AFTER EDITION
      val oldItemIdx = advicesList.indexOf(advicesList.filter(a => a.id == bean.id).head)
      advicesList.update(oldItemIdx, bean)
      event.getGrid.setItems(advicesList.asJava)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve the problem much better:

You have to get the `BeanItem` from the container and pass this to your editor window. There you can change the bean itself by asscessing it hrough the `BeanItem`s `Properies`. This is a very manual work so I use instead always databindg of `FieldGroup` - just call `bind`(field, "propertyName"); where propertyName is the getter method without get and non capital letter.