# How to refresh a vaadin page with the refresh button

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I need to refresh the page in vaadin. I created a Refresh Button but the button is not working for refreshing the page.

```
Button Refresh = new Button("Refresh");
Refresh.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What should happen in the `buttonClick()` method?

Comment: @AndréSchild I have creadted a grid in the page i want the grid to refresh again without any changes(search results, sorting ). Buttonclick method should make the page as it was on it's first access.

Comment: Is it a GridLayout or a data grid? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275944/how-can-you-refresh-a-vaadin-grid-after-data-change and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204674/update-grid-with-a-fresh-set-of-data-in-vaadin-7-4-app

Comment: In your code you've added a listener for the button, then a method that should do something when tie button is clicked... but the code for this method is empty :(. What do you expect to get if you haven't told him to do anything after the button is clicked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call this in your Button ClickListener:

```
Page.getCurrent().reload();
```

This reloads the page in the browser.

Answer (score 23):

For Vaadin 10:

Call this in your Button ClickListener:

```
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().reload();
```